# Does PySCF support CAS-SCF calculation?

Tags: electronic-structure, multi-reference

Does PySCF support CAS-SCF calculations? If not, it is possible to implement it based on their GTO integral library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does, and it is even quite efficient in it. Choosing the active space is also quite simple to do with the AVAS method if you know which atoms' valence orbitals you want to make active; alternatively, you can form UHF, MP2, or CISD etc natural orbitals and pick the active space based on them. I even believe that you can input your own integrals so that you can easily study also model systems.

Please see the user guide's MCSCF* section at https://pyscf.org/user/mcscf.html for details how to run the calculations

(*) CASSCF is a special type of MCSCF